# Facebook and Quickblox integration for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, quickblox

I am working on an iOS app which uses Quickblox SDK for chatting purpose. Also used Facebook SDK for login purpose. When used facebook login, quickblox uses loginWithSocialProvider method to login using facebook which always returns error. With Facebook api version upto 2.3 I'm able to create account and able to get successful response. But Facebook api version 2.4 and above I'm getting error response even with latest quickblox sdk 2.5 and FB SDK 4.6.0. Please help me figure out why this is happening. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your facebook token permissions, it should return correct email address in order to 'loginWithSocialProvider' work. Also please check that you are using this method in a correct way:

```
[QBRequest logInWithSocialProvider:@"facebook" accessToken:[[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] tokenString] accessTokenSecret:nil successBlock:^(QBResponse * _Nonnull response, QBUUser * _Nullable user) {
        //
        NSLog(@"Logged in as %@", [user description]);
    } errorBlock:^(QBResponse * _Nonnull response) {
        //
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", [response.error description]);
    }];
```

Comment: Already I checked with the Email address,and then proceed with 'loginWithSocialProvider',But even when I get a error response. Is there any alternative solution will be.

Comment: Can you provide the exect error here? Use my code to see detailed error.