# QuickBlox v2.6 Facebook login issue

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, quickblox

I have one issue facebook signing with quickblox api.
After getting AccessToken by using FBSDK.

```
[QBRequest logInWithSocialProvider:@"facebook" accessToken:accessToken accessTokenSecret:nil successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBUUser *user) {
} errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {}
```

i think facebook returns correct token string.

> CAAVS4qDIQb4BAMS7pTl3P1EmtW1ZCOOpbTCQFWrBI8QsA7ufOTYapjF3rEpW1ojZChgOZB7mj6AWDocDSdtxFbksqP3FyZCIou6bUC6ON4ZCRFGPes6TBzufh68A9fBSSz6baTYCZCTIyZAoDhYdBZAvrHF3609cAiEZCesnWrtqYleqPv7YHIadrWf2x1oWItypF3V3pbDgsHd7MSSCcZBvK4yuHGeCUvf7qMPFznuRZCfwNCOcQBDU8ynHnzDPpnnhLEZD

```
[logInWithSocialProvider: accessToken:  ...] function returns following error
    [QBResponse], status: 422
2015-12-09 14:27:27.049 NudgeBuddies[2598:124844] [QBCore] Response error: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: client error (422)" UserInfo={com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7ffde266ce40> { URL: https://api.quickblox.com/login.json } { status code: 422, headers {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 47;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Wed, 09 Dec 2015 06:27:26 GMT";
    "QB-Token-ExpirationDate" = "2015-12-09 08:27:26 UTC";
    "QuickBlox-REST-API-Version" = "0.1.1";
    Server = "nginx/1.6.2";
    Status = "422 Unprocessable Entity";
    "X-Rack-Cache" = "invalidate, pass";
    "X-Request-Id" = ab3443c24c0d5ee0a18d796eaf996cb7;
    "X-Runtime" = "0.221723";
    "X-UA-Compatible" = "IE=Edge,chrome=1";
} }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.quickblox.com/login.json, com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<7b226572 726f7273 223a7b22 62617365 223a5b22 4c6f6769 6e206f72 20656d61 696c2072 65717569 72656422 5d7d7d>, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: client error (422)}
```

Please Help me.
How can i solve this problem?
Regards.

Comment: i wanted to use this function [QBRequest logInWithSocialProvider:@"facebook" scope:permissionsArray successBlock:[self successBlock] errorBlock:[self errorBlock]]; but QB v2.6 doesn't support this function.

Comment: we are also faced the same issue , see this question once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33873110/facebook-and-quickblox-integration-for-ios,

Comment: can you print NSLog(@"Response error: %@", response.error);

Comment: Response error: Error reasons:(null)    ----- This is printed.

Answer (score 1):

1. In QuickBlox SDK 2.6.5 we have improved stability and we have enabled detail logging so you are able to see the reasons why problem happens.
2. QuickBlox has open source project [Q-municate](https://github.com/QuickBlox/q-municate-ios) with Facebook login and you can check it by yourself.

Thanks!